# Running python script at reboot

Tags: python, cron

On a headless raspberry pi I want to run a python script at reboot which continuous to run using tmux. From time to time I connect via ssh to get the data my python script collects.

All works fine when executed in the terminal but it doesn't work when executed by cron at reboot.

I've added to cron following:

```
0 3 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
@reboot /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s counter '/usr/bin/python /home/ted/counter.py'
```

After a reboot tmux ls gives following:
`no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default`

grep CRON /var/log/syslog gives me that:

```
> Sep  9 19:30:01 counter *CRON*[979]: (root) CMD (/sbin/shutdown -r
> now) Sep  9 19:30:26 counter cron[201]: (*CRON*) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
> Sep  9 19:30:26 counter cron[201]: (*CRON*) INFO (Running @reboot
> jobs) Sep  9 19:30:26 counter *CRON*[213]: (ted) CMD (/usr/bin/tmux
> new-session -d -s counter ‘/usr/bin/python /home/ted/counter.py’)
```

Any hint to get it running is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the hundreds of similar questions on this site?

Comment: you are asking in the wrong place ... your question is about linux

Comment: Look at other questions.  Likely your issue is among the many solved ones that have to do with your software requiring an env variable or some service type process that has yet to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I dropped the **cron** and **tmux** approach in favor of a **systemd** solution.

The reason for that change is, that I read somewhere that systemd is preferred over cron for similar tasks.

To get started I used the [Setup a python script as a service through systemctl/systemd](https://medium.com/codex/setup-a-python-script-as-a-service-through-systemctl-systemd-f0cc55a42267) article by WasiUllah Khan.

It didn't work right out of the box for my Python program which uses the serial library. For some reason it requires to add the user in the systemd service file by adding `User=pi` in the service section.

Now my Python program starts automatically after a reboot of the Raspberry Pi and I don't have to ssh into the machine to execute the program in tmux which I use to keep it running in the background.

I hope above is of help for others who need such a solution for a similar project.